# How to send a permanent (301) redirect from HTTP to HTTPS in Jetty 9

Tags: 301-redirect, jetty

After following the suggestion on [How to have Jetty redirect http to https](https://serverfault.com/questions/367660/how-to-have-jetty-redirect-http-to-https), we were able to get our standalone Jetty deployment to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS. The redirect however is a 302. How can we make this a 301 (permanent) redirect instead?

For reference, we added this to Jetty's etc/webdefault.xml:

```
<web-app>
  ...
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Everything in the webapp</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
      <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

Comment: @Drifter104 updated the question to specify what we did.

Comment: It appears  using org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.MovedContextHandler is the recommended way to do this. http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.0.6.v20130930/moved-context-handler.html

Comment: We were indeed able to get it to work using MovedContextHandler. Thanks @Drifter104 !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were able to get the desired behavior by adding a redirector.xml file next to the war. The contents of that file are below. Note that this will also redirect example.com to www.example.com:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.MovedContextHandler">
  <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
  <Set name="newContextURL">https://www.example.com</Set>
  <Set name="permanent">true</Set>
  <Set name="discardPathInfo">false</Set>
  <Set name="discardQuery">false</Set>

  <Set name="virtualHosts">
    <Array type="String">
      <Item>example.com</Item>
    </Array>
  </Set>
</Configure>
```